# Memory size error when updating data base despite chunking in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working in a Laravel project in version 4.2 (quite old, I know), trying to update a database table of around 100.000 entries. I am doing so by looping through a list of of 7500 users:

```
User::chunk(300, function($users){
                foreach($users as $user) {
                    CommunityView::deleteViews($user);
                    CommunityView::createDefaultView($user);
                    print("<br> update user ". $user->id);  
                }
            });
```

Even though I chunk the users, I receive memory size errors such as: `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes).` This is weird, because:

1. 2097160 < 134217728
2. I receive this error for bigger chunk sizes like 400, but also for a chunk size of 1
3. For a value like 50 or 100 for the chunk size, Laravel doesn't return any error, but just does not finish the script and stops after around one minute processing time, after around 30-40% of the job is done.

The functions deleteViews() and createDefaultView() look more or less like this:

```
public static function createDefaultView(User $user) {
        $communityView = new CommunityView();
        $communityView->user_id = $user->id;
        $communityView->name = "Forum";
        $communityView->save();
}

public static function deleteViews(User $user) {
        DB::table('threads_views')
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('deleted_at', NULL)
            ->update(
                ['deleted_at' => DB::raw("NOW()")]);
}
```

Why do I get these problems? Isn't the point of chunking to process entry by entry so that memory errors should not arise?

Comment: That error normally comes with a file name and line number? Does yours

Comment: _For reference_ The error is saying you have already allocated 134217728 bytes and now you want to allocate an additional 2097160. If I did that I would blow the Max memory limit

Comment: The error message points to `/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/DataCollector/QueryCollector.php`, to line 114 `$this->queries[] = array('query' => $query, 'bindings' => $this->escapeBindings($bindings),`. I think that's not really useful?

Comment: Try disabling the debugbar and see what happens. Set `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` in `.env` and clear cached config.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in Laravel 4.2. I didn't have an `.env` file yet, so I created one in in the root directory and added `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false` and `APP_DEBUG=false`. I then flushed the cache with `php artisan cache:clear` (command `config:clear` is not defined), but it does not disable debugbar. If I remove debugbar from app.php, I receive the error `file_put_contents(/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Comment: I tried again to disable debugbar by commenting it out in app.php and suprisingly the error changed, I got `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. I could then run my script quite far by temporarily increasing the time limit with `set_time_limit()`. The script now runs longer than before, it finishes 90-95% of the work and then stops without throwing an error.